# Accessing one data from column with many rows

Tags: laravel

How can i get year,month & day separately from database dynamically.(Note.this column has multiple rows.)
Database data example:
2015-08-13 ,
2016-07-31 ,
2016-08-02

```
public function index()
    {

//scholar_birthday - column name
$bday = Scholar::select('scholar_birthday')->get();
dd($bday);
$date = explode("-", $bday);

$d = $date[2];
$m = $date[1];
$y = $date[0];

<!--Static Data-->  
//$year = '1991';
//$month = '12';
//$day = '19';

$howOldAmI = Carbon::createFromDate($y,$m,$d)->age;

dd($howOldAmI,$bday);
        return view('pages.Index');
    }
```

This code is not working!Hope anyone can fix this logic for me.

Updated code:With error "Unknown or bad timezone ([{"scholar_birthday":"1221-02-13 00:00:00"},"
Database: Header |scholar_birthday|
          Value  |2015-08-13      |
Is something wrong with my data or it has something to do with the setting for timezone in phpmyadmin or laravel?
Here is the code:

```
public function index()
{       
$bday = Scholar::select('scholar_birthday')->get();
$format = 'y/m/d';
$year = 'y';
$month = 'm';
$day = 'd';
$data = Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day,$bday);

dd($data);
        return view('pages.Index');
    }
}
```

Update.Dob-separate database for trial and error only.My actual work is the Scholar model from the other databse.And this is how i save the date input from my blade.php
Note:I've saved the date input to database in a single column.Is it correct or do i need to save the y/m/d in separate column?But this is my input"`<input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" >"`.So this will be saved as single column.This way how can i apply your code in accessing the data?

```
$date = $request->input('date');
        $dob = new Dob;
        $dateOfBirth = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$date,'UTC')
        ->tz('UTC')
        ->toDateString(); // '2014-02-21'
        $dob->date_of_birth = $dateOfBirth;
        $dob->save();
        return view('pages.Ngo.AddDob');
```

//This the controller

```
$bday = Dob::select('date_of_birth')->get();
```

The problem is here...

```
$age = Carbon::createFromDate(,,,$bday)->age;
```

What i want to achieve here is to get the age.What is wrong with the code here:

```
$today = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$bday = Dob::select('date_of_birth')->get();
$age = $bday->diff($today)->age;
```

error:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
    dd($age);

/database table/

```
  id 
  2

   date_of_birth               
   2016-12-07 

   created_at  
   2016-12-04 12:47:59 

   updated_at 
   2016-12-04 12:47:59
```

Comment: Is scholar_birthday created as a date object?

Comment: @Scott Plunkett -Sir, i set my database as varchar for the date.Since it is a string.I want to access separately according to what i want.Its either be the year or month but in my case, I want the y/m/d separately so i can put it in the parameter Carbon::createFromDate($y,$m,$d) dynamically.I've tested static data and its working fine.The reason i want this all rows for this scholar_birthday column its because i want to compare and get diff from current date get the age.This age then is for comparison to locate the matching age that i want to retrieve.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Did you try my answer below?

Comment: @Scott Plunkett - Sir i've update my code and the error now is InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 156: Unknown or bad timezone ([{"scholar_birthday":"1221-02-13 00:00:00"},{"scholar_birthday":"2016-08-31 00:00:00"},{"scholar_birthday":"2016-08-02 00:00:00"},{"scholar_birthday":"2016-08-06 00:00:00"},{"scholar_birthday":"2016-09-02 00:00:00"},{"scholar_birthday":"2016-07-31 00:00:00"},{"scholar_birthday":"2016-11-17 00:00:00"},{"scholar_birthday":"2015-08-13 00:00:00"},{"scholar_birthday":"2016-08-27 00:00:00"}])    This is the setting 'timezone' => 'UTC',  in my app.php.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through the hassle of getting a specific value by using explode(), just pass the original date as a date object.

In your model (Scholar.php in app/ by default) add the following:

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at', // If you are using softDeletes
    'scholar_birthday
];
```

Once you add the column to the date mutator, we will use Carbon to do all the heavy lifting for us. Make sure anywhere you use the Carbon facade you add the appropriate use statement:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Then, when adding the birthday to the database, add it as a Carbon object like so:

```
Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day, 'UTC');
```

Once you save the entry, to retrieve a specific day/month/year from this object, do the following:

```
$scholar = Scholar::find($idOfScholar);
$bday    = $scholar->scholar_birthday

Day: $bday->day
Month: $bday->month
Year: $bday->year
```

This will get a single. Otherwise, you'll need to iterate from row to row with a foreach() or other looping mechanism.

Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: This is what i did but it generates an error "Unknown or bad timezone "----Updated code:public function index()
{  
$bday = Scholar::select('scholar_birthday')->get();
$format = 'y/m/d';
$year = 'y';
$month = 'm';
$day = 'd';
$data = Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day,$bday);

dd($data);
  return view('pages.Index');
 }
}

Comment: Untested but I fixed the time zone.

Comment: Sir in my database, the dob was saved as string .I'm wondering why its looking for a timezone which is not needed for me.I only need to extract the date by year/month/day.

Comment: You were getting that error when CREATING the date object. Not retrieving it. The time zone is needed to create the date object when storing it in the database.

Comment: Sir please look my update code above.I'd saved the date input as single column using date picker.How can i access the year,month and day separately?

Comment: I dont think it can be treated as object since it is being save as single column from one input only.

Comment: Did you add the column into the protected $dates array?

Comment: Yes sir:    protected $dates = [
    'date_of_birth',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
 ];

Comment: Your code isn't exactly correct. To get the day, month, and year you need to call ->day, ->month, or ->year on your select object. Don't create another carbon instance. It will be created off of the database ->get().

Comment: day,month and year is undefined   $bday->year

Comment: Is there more than one row matching your query? More than one row will require you to loop through them.

Comment: It has many rows Sir,actually i will get all the data under this column.

Comment: As I said you will need to iterate through those rows. You cannot call the methods without iteration.